# prove the next inequality $a_n=\frac {\ln (n+1)(2n-1)}{\ln (n)(2n+1)}<1$

Tags: calculus, inequality

How to show that the element is less than one? From a certain $n$ onwards.

$$a_n=\frac {(2n-1)\ln (n+1)}{(2n+1)\ln (n)}<1$$

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality is equivalent to $$(2n-1)\ln(n+1)<(2n+1)\ln(n)$$

equivalent to $$(n+1)^{2n-1}<n^{2n+1}$$

equivalent to $$\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right]^{\frac{2n-1}{n}}<n^2$$

But $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}<e$. Therefore $$\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right]^{\frac{2n-1}{n}}<e^{\frac{2n-1}{n}}=e^{2-\frac{1}{n}}<e^{2}<n^2$$ for $n$ large ($n\geq3$ should be large enough).

Comment: $\frac {\ln (n+1)(2n-1)}{\ln (n)(2n+1)} > \frac {\ln (n+1)(2n-1)}{\ln (n+1)(2n+1)}$  $\frac {\ln (n+1)(2n-1)}{\ln (n+1)(2n+1)} = \frac {(2n-1)}{(2n+1)}$ $\frac {(2n-1)}{(2n+1)} < 1$ for $n>1$ will that work as well?

Comment: It is true that for $n=2$ it is also true, but be careful on how you prove it. You have there inequalities pointing in the opposite directions.

Comment: I have shown that a greater element than the original is less than 1, isn't it adequate proof?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to write that, but in the first inequality you wrote $>$ while in the second you wrote $<$. Independently of them being correct or not, that is what I was saying you should avoid.

Answer (score 2):

We just need to prove that $\frac{2n+1}{\log(n+1)}$ is an increasing function. But if:

$$ f(x) = \frac{2x+1}{\log(x+1)} $$
we have:
$$ f'(x) = \frac{2}{\log(x+1)}-\frac{(2x+1)}{(x+1)\log^2(x+1)}=\frac{2(x+1)\log(x+1)-(2x+1)}{(x+1)\log^2(x+1)} $$
and $f'(x)>0$ is equivalent to:
$$\log(x+1)>\frac{2x+1}{2x+2} $$
that holds for sure as soon as $x\geq 2 >e-1.$